# Check if multiple circles could fit inside one circle

Tags: php, math

I got a programming task where I need to do some mathematical operations but I am totally stuck.

Lets say I got a round tube with **10 cm diameter**, this equals to **5 cm radius** and the area of this tube is PI*r^2 ~ **78.54 cm2**

Now lets say I have 3 smaller tubes that is also round, that I want to check if fit inside this larger tube, how can I do so?

Lets take an example, the 3 smaller tubes can be **4 cm diameter**, which equals to **2 cm radius**, and the area of each single small tube is PI*r^2 ~ **12.56 cm2**.

So **12.56 * 3 = 37.68 cm2**. So now I know that the total area of the 3 smaller circles is less then the area of the larger circle (**78.54 cm2**) so my conclusion is that it will fit.

And if you try it yourself on a piece of paper, you will see that it does.

This is the problem:

Now what if we were to try and put 2 smaller round tubes with a **diameter of 7 cm** inside that large tube instead of the 3 smaller tubes that had **4 cm diameter**.

So just a quick review here, now we got 1 large round tube with a **diameter of 10 cm** and we want to try and put 2 smaller round tubes inside that large tube the 2 small tubes has a **diameter of 7 cm**.

Now if I calculate the area of each of the smaller tubes it is PI*r^2 ~ **38.48 cm2**. So since we have 2 of the smaller tubes, the total area would be **38.48 * 2 = 76.96 cm2**. And **76.96 cm2** is less then the larger main tube which is **78.54 cm2** so my application would expect it to fit.

However it would not actually fit. Now I am stuck and don't know how to check if it would fit or not, since checking the total area seems useless in this case.

Please help a desperate math dummy overcome this problem.

Comment: Lol where is the PHP code?

Comment: I tagged it both as math and php. Math, cause it's a math question. And php cause I am using php in case anyone would know some php function that provides an easy solution for this problem. Anyways I don't see why you would need the code, but sure if you want to see my 6 lines of code I'll provide them for you. All it does is the exact calculation I did above but in code instead of raw text.

Comment: This touches on open problems in mathematics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle , although this is only an issue if you are trying to fit a large number of smaller circles in the bigger circle. Also, this might be helpful: http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/smaller-circles-in-larger-circle-d_1849.html

Comment: Thanks @JohnColeman